# ScalaTest: BeforeAndAfter not running

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest

I am trying to learn how to use fixture setup and teardown in ScalaTest. One example I have been trying is the following:

```
import org.scalatest._
import scala.collection.mutable

class SampleTest extends FlatSpec with BeforeAndAfter with Matchers{

  before {
     // Setup code
  }

  after {
    // Teardown code
  }

  "A Stack" should "pop values in last-in-first-out order" in {
    val stack = new mutable.Stack[Int]
    stack.push(1)
    stack.push(2)
    stack.pop() should be (2)
    stack.pop() should be (1)
  }

  it should "throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped" in {
    val emptyStack = new mutable.Stack[Int]
    a [NoSuchElementException] should be thrownBy {
      emptyStack.pop()
    }
  }
}
```

The trouble with this is that neither of the before or after blocks are being executed at all. I feel I have followed the instructions in the project docs perfectly - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add your ScalaTest imports to the code above? I think it should work.

Comment: @colinjwebb, yep, they have been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had to add explicit override modifiers to before and after:

```
override def before: Any = println("Doing before")

override def after: Any = println("Doing after")
```

However, it should be noted that there most likely is something wrong with my environment, not TestScala. I have not seen anyone else having this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I tried your example and it runs fine:

```
import org.scalatest._
import scala.collection.mutable

class SampleSpec extends FlatSpec with BeforeAndAfter with Matchers{

  before {
    info("Setup code")
  }

  after {
    info("Teardown code")
  }

  "A Stack" should "pop values in last-in-first-out order" in {
    val stack = new mutable.Stack[Int]
    stack.push(1)
    stack.push(2)
    stack.pop() should be (2)
    stack.pop() should be (1)
  }

  it should "throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped" in {
    val emptyStack = new mutable.Stack[Int]
    a [NoSuchElementException] should be thrownBy {
      emptyStack.pop()
    }
  }
}
```

Pasting it into the REPL gives you:

```
scala> new SampleSpec execute
SampleSpec:
A Stack
+ Setup code 
- should pop values in last-in-first-out order
+ Teardown code 
+ Setup code 
- should throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped
+ Teardown code
```

However, given you comment about needing to say "override def," I think I know what is going on. I think your IDE may have completed your code to BeforeAndAfterEach, even though you wanted BeforeAndAfter. So you mixed in BeforeAndAfterEach, which indeed requires :override def before..." but were looking at the documentation for BeforeAndAfter. Can you double check and see if that was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

it can also be, if one does not have any tests written by mistake for example commented put the tests like `"A Stack" should "pop values in last-in-first-out order" in { blah blah blah the test code }` , then the before and after will never be called